# How to get back rows from a spreadsheet in SharePoint based on a search

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2013

I have an excel spreadsheet in SharePoint, it has close to 2000 rows.  I would like to return all rows that match a search criteria.  Typically, it will be either Project ID or a person's name.

I know that I can retrieve the complete spreadsheet using  **ExcelRest** via the command below, but I need to only return those records that match my search criteria which should always be less than 100 rows.  The actual spreadsheet using the command below does not come back, since the request entity is too large.

```
https://MySite/teams/MES/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/MMIS/MESRACI.xlsx/model/Ranges('RACI')?$format=html
```

Is there a trick where I can pass a parameter in the above command and return a subset of rows that match the criteria I'm passing in?  I am only thinking about searching for a name and possible a project id, but these would be two separate instances and would not be done in the same search.

Comment: looks like the ExcelRest API doesn't support search, so, no.

Comment: Correct, but it does support sending a parameter to a range.  I was thinking of using that range to fill another Range of data that would be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it took a lot of playing around, but I finally got it.
My original spreadsheet is 2000 lines long that has all the data.
I created a range on another sheet that would pull in the individual that was stored in another named Range on another sheet.  This allows me to have a smaller subset of records that display only the records that were in the named range as a search.

I then use EXCELREST and passed in the Range I want to bring back along with the value of the Named Range that I'm setting it to.

It works perfectly.  The difficult thing was to create the second sheet to display the data of the individuals I was looking for.  Since a person would exists from none to 100 times in the main spreadsheet, I had to build the second sheet to find each occurrence.

An example of the formula I used on the second spreadsheet is:
    =INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("RACI!$A$",$V2+3)):RACI!$V$2010,MATCH(Setup!$B$2,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("RACI!$F$",$V2+3)):RACI!$F$2010,0),1)

The command line is like:
    https://mysite.gov/hc/teams/MES/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/MMIS/MESRACI.xlsx/model/Ranges('SearchedRACI')?$format=html&Ranges(%27NameFilter%27)=Sxxele,%20Craig%20A.

The last trick was to bring back the row number of each record that I found and to limit the range for searching to be beyond that position.